# PHP ImageMagick use 10gb~ memory when resizing a big image

Tags: resize, imagemagick, ram

I have problem when I try to resize a very big image like a 30,000px x 20,000px with ImageMagick software. But I do not have enought RAM. I have 8GB, but the software requires about 10GB~. I need to use all data in RAM. I tried two options:

1 using *convert*, writes to a different image file:

```
convert -resize 90% source.jpg destination.jpg
```

2. using *mogrify* overwrites the original image file

   mogrify -resize 90% source.jpg

Maybe someone knows how I can use less memory or some other tricks.

More information about Imagemagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your attempting to configure ImageMagick's memory polices to use more RAM, before caching to disk, define the AREA limit by modifying policy.xml or set an environment variable.

#### Setting Memory limit in Environment

This is probably the quickest way for one-off process.

```
MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT=8GB convert -resize 90% source.jpg destination.jpg
```

Also attempt adjusting other environment vars

- `MAGICK_MAP_LIMIT` - Maximum amount of memory map in megabytes to allocate for the pixel cache.
- `MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT` - Maximum amount of memory in megabytes to allocate for the pixel cache from the heap.

#### Setting Memory limit with Policy.xml

Edit the `policy.xml` under your `{$PREFIX}/lib/ImageMagic-X.X.X/config` directory.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policymap [
<!ELEMENT policymap (policy)+>
<!ELEMENT policy (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST policy domain (delegate|coder|filter|path|resource) #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy name CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy rights CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy pattern CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy value CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
<policymap>
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="8GB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="8GB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="8GB"/>
</policymap>
```

#### Verification

Whatever method you choose, you can verify by running the `identify` utility.

```
$ identify -list resource

  File       Area     Memory        Map       Disk   Thread  Throttle       Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1920        8GB        8GB        8GB  unlimited        1         0  unlimited
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve overall, but you can resize an image *while reading it* like this and it should take less memory:

```
convert source.jpg'[15000x10000]' destination.jpg
```

Comment: `convert.exe: unable to open image source.jpg'[10000x5000]'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2617.
convert.exe: unable to open module file C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.7Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_JPG'[10000X5000]'_.dll': No such file or directory @ warning/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/683.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format source.jpg'[10000x5000]''
 @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert.exe: no images defined destination.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageC
ommand/3021.`

Comment: Your quotes do not match - you start with a single one and end with a double one...

Comment: Please also try without any quotes at all as I am not sure how the PHP bindings work since I use the commandline and Perl.

Comment: without quotes: `convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format C:/Users/UserXX/AppData/
Local/Temp/magick-rIQSBQOj' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.`

Comment: You seem to have got a space in the directory path in front of `Local`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `policy.xml` which resides under `/etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml`

In my case it was using more than 2GiB, but here you can limit so that script should be running under the provided limit. I set it for 512MiB for `map` and `memory`.